# How to Optimize/Refactor MySQL Pivot Table Performance when using Where Clause

Tags: mysql, optimization, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I have two simple MySQL tables - one index table `t_id`, which has a unique primary id; and a pivot table `t_data` spreading those id's over various data fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_id` (  
  `id` bigint(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `t_data` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `field` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,  
  `value` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
DEFAULT NULL,  
  UNIQUE KEY `idxfield` (`id`,`field`),  
  KEY `value` (`value`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is some sample data:

```
+----+--------------+-------------------+  
| id | field        | value             |  
+----+--------------+-------------------+  
| 1  | organization | Apple Inc.        |  
| 1  | state        | CA                |  
| 2  | organization | Adobe Inc.        |  
| 2  | state        | CA                |  
| 3  | organization | Alphabet Inc.     |  
| 3  | state        | CA                |  
| 4  | organization | Rockwell Collins  |  
| 4  | state        | IA                |  
| 5  | organization | GEICO             |  
| 5  | state        | MD                |  
| 6  | organization | Anheuser-Busch    |  
| 6  | state        | MO                |  
| 7  | organization | Bank of America   |  
| 7  | state        | NC                |  
+----+--------------+-------------------+
```

which can be reported on with a standard pivot table select query:

```
select  
  i.id,  
  ifnull (max(case when d.field = 'organization' then d.value end),'') 'organization',  
  ifnull (max(case when d.field = 'state' then d.value end),'') 'state'  
from `t_id` i  
left join `t_data` d  
on i.id = d.id  
group by i.id  
limit 0,10
```

This simple example shows just two "virtual" fields (organization and state), with 7 unique id's:

```
+----+------------------+-------+  
| id | organization     | state |  
+----+------------------+-------+  
| 1  | Apple Inc.       |  CA   |  
| 2  | Adobe Inc.       |  CA   |  
| 3  | Alphabet Inc.    |  CA   |  
| 4  | Rockwell Collins |  IA   |  
| 5  | GEICO            |  MD   |  
| 6  | Anheuser-Busch   |  MO   |  
| 7  | Bank of America  |  NC   |  
+----+------------------+-------+
```

In our actual production situation we have dozens of "virtual" fields (not just 2), and millions of unique id's (not just 7).  The database performs quite well doing crud type queries on single id's (less than a second), and even listing one limit group at a time (again less than a second).  The problem arises when an attempt is made to constrain a select with a where clause (queries are taking tens of seconds).  For example, to find all the organizations in California:

```
select  
 x.id,  
 x.organization,  
 x.state  
from  
(  
select  
  i.id,  
  ifnull (max(case when d.field = 'organization' then d.value end),'') 'organization',  
  ifnull (max(case when d.field = 'state' then d.value end),'') 'state'  
from `t_id` i  
left join `t_data` d  
on i.id = d.id  
group by i.id  
) as x  
where x.state='CA'  
limit 0,10  


+----+---------------+-------+  
| id | organization  | state |  
+----+---------------+-------+  
| 1  | Apple Inc.    |  CA   |  
| 2  | Adobe Inc.    |  CA   |  
| 3  | Alphabet Inc. |  CA   |  
+----+---------------+-------+
```

this works but it takes a LONG time (again, 10's of seconds)!  What is the best practice here - is there a better way to write these types of queries?  How can these pivot table queries be optimized for a where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a lot faster with large data sets.  Plus it can easily be extended to any number of "virtual" fields.  You can place any search criteria you may have between the %%.

```
select  
    i.id,  
    coalesce(max(case when field = 'organization' then value end), '') as organization,  
    coalesce(max(case when field = 'state' then value end), '') as state  
from t_id i  
left join t_data d  
on i.id = d.id  
and i.id like '%%'  
and i.id in (  
  select id  
  from `t_data`  
  where `field` = 'organization'   
  and `value` like '%%'  
  and  id  in (  
    select id  
    from `t_data`  
    where `field` = 'state'  
    and `value` like '%%'  
  )  
)  
group by i.id
```

Comment: My posted query (with the subquery) took 37.09 sec on my populated data set with 5 "virtual" fields.
The @Tim_Biegeleisen "HAVING" solution took 16.17 sec, executing in 43.6% of my time.
Your solution took 1.54 sec, executing in 4.2% of my time.  Thank both of you!  I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find organizations operating in the state of California you don't actually need a subquery:

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'organization' THEN value END), '') AS organization,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'state' THEN value END), '') AS state
FROM t_id i
LEFT JOIN t_data d
    ON i.id = d.id
GROUP BY
    i.id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 'state' AND value = 'CA' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

The trick here is to assert in the `HAVING` clause that a matching `id` group needs to have a record for `state` in California.

Comment: Many thanks.  Still takes quite a while to execute but approximately twice as fast as using the subquery (14.80 sec vs 37.09 sec).  BTW, typo - it's COALESCE, not COALESECE.  What would be the syntax of a HAVING clause with 2 constraints - e.g. WHEN field = 'organization' AND value = 'Apple Inc.' + WHEN field = 'state' AND value = 'CA'  ?

Comment: I _think_ you would just want to add an additional condition to my `HAVING` clause: `COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 'state' AND value 'CA' THEN 1 END) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

This is EAV, not Pivot.  So, the solution lies in a "self join".

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.value AS organization,
        b.value AS state
    FROM t_data AS a
    JOIN t_data AS b  ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.field = 'organization'
      AND b.field = 'state';
```

If you need `t_id` to control which ids, slip in

```
    JOIN t_id AS i  ON i.id = a.id
```

If you want to limit to CA, tack on

```
      AND b.value = 'CA'
```

and add

```
INDEX(field, value)
```

so it won't have to scan as many rows to find the CA entries.